# While Downloading pdf async if i go back and again initiate VC then it doesn't change UI i.e button title

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, download

When i start download using async task with the help of afnetworking it downloads properly even if i go back and com again the download is on its way only but when i again go to the same download screen breakpoint also comes on the screen but it doesnt change any title of button or any such UI action

Here is my code for downloading

```
- (void) downloadByURL:(NSString *)URL
{

    [self.progress setHidden:NO];
    [self.btnsubscribe setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *session = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *tasks=
    [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL * _Nonnull(NSURL * _Nonnull targetPath, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response) {
        //
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.ILModel.IssueID] stringByAppendingString:self.ILModel.Month] stringByAppendingString:self.ILModel.Year] stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"]];
        return [NSURL URLWithString: path];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, NSURL * _Nonnull filePath, NSError * _Nonnull error) {


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
             [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] writeToFile:[filePath absoluteString] atomically:YES];
            [self.progress setHidden:YES];
            [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Download Complete" duration:2.0f];

            [self.btnsubscribe setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"5BE4CA"]];
            [self.btnsubscribe setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.btnsubscribe setTitle:@"View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             [self.btnsubscribe setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        });
    }];

    [session setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock:^(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask, int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

        int prog= (int)(totalBytesWritten * 100 / totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

        [self.progress setHidden:NO];
        [self.btnsubscribe setTitle:@"Downloading" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [KSToastView ks_showToast:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloaded %lld %%",totalBytesWritten * 100 / totalBytesExpectedToWrite] duration:1.0f];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setLoaderProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)prog/100] waitUntilDone:NO];

        NSLog(@"Progress… %lld",totalBytesWritten * 100 / totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];

    [tasks resume];
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the UI task in the background thread.

Do it in the following manner:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {

             [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] writeToFile:[filePath absoluteString] atomically:YES];
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   [self.progress setHidden:YES];
                   [KSToastView ks_showToast:@"Download Complete" duration:2.0f];
                   [self.btnsubscribe setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"5BE4CA"]];
                   [self.btnsubscribe setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   [self.btnsubscribe setTitle:@"View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   [self.btnsubscribe setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
             });
});
```

Comment: i am taking about this part.
[session setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock:^(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask, int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

        int prog= (int)(totalBytesWritten * 100 / totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

        [self.progress setHidden:NO];
        [self.btnsubscribe setTitle:@"Downloading" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [KSToastView ks_showToast:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloaded %lld %%",totalBytesWritten * 100 / totalBytesExpectedToWrite] duration:1.0f];

       
    }];

Comment: just a moment let me try

Comment: No its not working. My problem is when i go back and again come on this downloading screen then i think all the values are lost